# Notificações no navegador

Tags: javascript, html5

Eu reparei que alguns sites por exemplo o facebook, quando alquem escreve no chat aparece uma notificação no navegador mesmo se tiver o facebook fechado o mesmo acontece com sites de noticias que ao subescrever quando sai uma noticia nova recebo a notificação no navegador entao eu gostava de ter uma ideia como isso se programa, se é javascript ou html5 é que não tenho mesmo ideia como isso funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que esteja procurando por notificação de área de trabalho, correto? Aqui está bem esclarecido e com exemplo, mas em inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example